# Зачем в Java 9 добавили List.of

Tags: java, java-9

Зачем в Java 9 добавили `List.of` с несколькими сигнатурами?

Например, есть:

1. `<E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3)`
2. `<E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2)`
3. `<E> List<E> of(E e1)`
   ...
4. `<E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10)`

При этом в той же Java 9 сразу добавили:
`<E> List<E> of(E... elements)`,
который заменяет все предыдущие методы. Тогда в чем их смысл?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JEP 269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269):

> These will include varargs overloads, so that there is no fixed limit
>   on the collection size. However, the collection instances so created
>   may be tuned for smaller sizes. Special-case APIs (fixed-argument
>   overloads) for up to ten of elements will be provided. **While this
>   introduces some clutter in the API, it avoids array allocation,
>   initialization, and garbage collection overhead that is incurred by
>   varargs calls.** Significantly, the source code of the call site is
>   the same regardless of whether a fixed-arg or varargs overload is
>   called.

Джошуа Блох - Java Эффективное программирование (статья 42):

> Нужно быть осторожными при использовании возможностей varargs в
>   ситуациях, где критична производительность. Каждый запуск метода с
>   переменным числом параметров приводит к созданию и инициализации
>   массива. Если вы понимаете, что не можете позволить себе такие
>   расходы, но вам нужна гибкость методов varargs, есть шаблон, который
>   позволит совместить преимущества обоих подходов. Предположим, вы
>   определили, что 95% обращений к методу содержит 3 и менее параметров.
>   Тогда объявим 5 перегрузок метода, каждый с количеством обычных
>   параметров от нуля до трёх, и один метод varargs для использования,
>   когда количество аргументов превысит 3:
>
> ```
> public void foo() { }
> public void foo(int a1) { }
> public void foo(int a1, int a2) { }
> public void foo(int a1, int a2, int a3) { }
> public void foo(int a1, int a2, int a3, int... rest) { }
> ```
>
> Теперь вы знаете, что затраты на создание массивов составят лишь 5% от
>   всех вызовов в случаях, где количество параметров будет больше трёх.

Answer (score 6):

**Для оптимизации**.

Тут важно отметить, что **возвращаемые такими методами коллекции являются неизменяемыми**. Т.е. мы можем сделать класс, который имеет два поля (первый и второй элемент) вместо массива (это аж 8 байт памяти) или другой структуры, и в этих полях держать значения. Соответственно при запросе размера коллекции мы можем сразу вернуть константу `2`, а **не искать это значение через дополнительные операции**. И так далее.

Собственно вот пример из [сырцов OpenJdk](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#L177) `List` класса для `<E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2)`

```
static final class List2<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> {
    @Stable
    private final E e0;
    @Stable
    private final E e1;

    List2(E e0, E e1) {
        this.e0 = Objects.requireNonNull(e0);
        this.e1 = Objects.requireNonNull(e1);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        Objects.checkIndex(index, 2);
        if (index == 0) {
            return e0;
        } else { // index == 1
            return e1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return o.equals(e0) || o.equals(e1); // implicit nullcheck of o
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 31 + e0.hashCode();
        return 31 * hash + e1.hashCode();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("not serial proxy");
    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new CollSer(CollSer.IMM_LIST, e0, e1);
    }
}
```

P.S. Могу добавить интересный аргумент. К примеру во всем известной `IntelliJ Idea` есть оптимизированная реализация для `List`, у которого всего один элемент. И  [даже есть видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZgbKcSRTgg), где один из разработчиков объясняет, что таким образом они стремятся сэкономить память.

Comment: Ок, я вижу оптимизации для 1 и 2 элементов, но методов скопировано аж для 10 элементов, а для них оптимизаций нет.

Comment: @victorKhovanskiy они могут появится в других реализациях/версиях JDK, без поломки внешнего API. Тем более это реализация `OpenJdk`, вполне возможно, что в `Oracle Jdk` есть классы для всех 10 вариантов.